# Using Dates in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I have a TEXT column called "time" in a table meal and in a table pain which is TEXT formatted as YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM. I'm trying to search for other times that are within 12 hours of a given time, although I can't figure out how to do that.

I've tried testing

```
WHERE pain.time < meal.time + "1:00" AND pain.time > meal.time
```

but this approach alters the year instead of the hour. I also tried testing the same query adding "0000-00-00T01:00", but it doesn't seem to do anything.
I'm not sure what else to test.

Comment: you should show the full query if possible, it will be easier for people to answer.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite has no built-in date/time data type, so you have to use [either numbers or strings](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime) and handle them correctly.

To do calculations, you have to either do them directly on the numerical value (which might require conversions into a number and back), or use the modifiers of the [built-in date/time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

```
... WHERE meal.time BETWEEN datetime(pain.time, '-12 hours') AND pain.time
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm not sure how to use date/time functions though. I tried running a select query `SELECT datetime(pain.time, '-12 hours') from pain;` just to see if it would alter the times, and it returns a blank result.

Comment: The date/time format you said you're using is supported by SQLite. `SELECT datetime('2014-04-23T12:34')` works. Is that the format you're actually using?

Comment: Yes, although how do I retrieve the datetime from the textfield, alter it, and then do a query querying between two altered datetimes? Like querying between the original datetime + - 12 hours?

Comment: If `SELECT datetime(pain.time, '-12 hours') from pain;` does not work, then you are not using a correct date format.

Comment: The code I'm using to insert values is: `INSERT INTO pain VALUES(null, "2014-02-23T12:00", 9, "Abdomonal", "Hurt a lot underneath belly button.");` and the table is `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pain (
 ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
 time TEXT,
 rating INT,
 location TEXT,
 description TEXT
);`